# Know what has been done in Windows 7 with time

Tags: windows-7

I want to Know what has been done in Windows 7 with time.
suppose I let my friend to use my desktop, but I am wonder if I can know what has been done in my PC while I was not there.
So is there any way to know that with time?

thanks!
Regards,

Comment: Had you enabled any additional logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Event Viewer for viewing the events on the time basis but it will not log each and every activity of the user.

See this for more info
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7